# Value Error from arcpy.getLayerExtent

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, valueerror

The objective of the following code is to pan the main map to the definition queried point and then zoom or pan the vicinity map to the county the point is contained in. I have working code for other figures that do not have vicinity maps. Here is that code below.

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"C:\Users\neuce\Documents\Projects\HouseMapping\ArcGIS\Figure 02.aprx")
m = aprx.listMaps()[0]
lyt = aprx.listLayouts()[0]
mf = lyt.listElements('MAPFRAME_ELEMENT')[0]
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(tempSites, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        for lyr in m.listLayers():
            if lyr.name == "Site":
                lyr.definitionQuery = "Match_addr = '{0}'".format(row[0])
                print("DQ applied "+ row[0])
                mf.panToExtent(mf.getLayerExtent(lyr))
                for txt in lyt.listElements('TEXT_ELEMENT'):
                    if txt.name == "Address":
                        txt.text = "{0} \n {1}, {2} {3}".format(row[2],row[4],row[3],row[5])
                print("panned")
                aprx.save()
                print("Saved")
                lyt.exportToPDF(r"C:\Users\neuce\Documents\Projects\HouseMapping\Figure 2 - {0}.pdf".format(row[0]))
                print("exported")

del aprx
```

But when I try and work with multiple mapframes I start getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\neuce\Documents\Projects\HouseMapping\Base Script.py", line 35, in <module>
    mf.panToExtent(mf.getLayerExtent(lyr))
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\_mp.py", line 1396, in getLayerExtent
    return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.getLayerExtent(*gp_fixargs((layer, selection_only, symbolized_extent), True)))
ValueError: <MappingLayerObject object at 0x000001BFD2450D30>
```

Here is my current code:

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"C:\Users\neuce\Documents\Projects\HouseMapping\ArcGIS\Figure 01test.aprx")
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(tempSites, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        m = aprx.listMaps()[0]
        lyt = aprx.listLayouts()[0]
        mf = lyt.listElements('MAPFRAME_ELEMENT')[0]
        for lyr in m.listLayers():
            if lyr.name == "Site":
                lyr.definitionQuery = "Match_addr = '{0}'".format(row[0])
                print("DQ applied "+ row[0])
                mf.panToExtent(mf.getLayerExtent(lyr))
                for txt in lyt.listElements('TEXT_ELEMENT'):
                    if txt.name == "Address":
                        txt.text = "{0} \n {1}, {2} {3}".format(row[2],row[4],row[3],row[5])
                print("panned")
                aprx.save()
                print("Saved")
        m = aprx.listMaps()[1]
        lyt = aprx.listLayouts()[1]
        mf = lyt.listElements('MAPFRAME_ELEMENT')[1]
        for lyr in m.listLayers():
            if lyr.name == 'CentralCoastalCounties':
                lyr.definitionQuery = "CNTY_NM = '{0}'".format(row[1])
                print("county DQ applied")
                mf.camera.setExtent(mf.getLayerExtent(lyr))
                lyr.definitionQuery = ""
                print("County DQ removed")
                aprx.save()
                lyt.exportToPDF(r"C:\Users\neuce\Documents\Projects\HouseMapping\Figure 1 - {0}.pdf".format(row[0]))
                print("exported")



del aprx
```

I think the value error means that the layer object doesn't contain something it should but i don't know what it needs.

Comment: This isn't arcgis-desktop, it's ArcGIS Pro which is a slightly different interface, I've modified the tags to help the appropriate users locate your question. Have you checked the layer is valid (layer.isBroken == False) before trying to get the extent?

Answer (score 1):

I tinkered around with the code and changed the index of the mapframes to no luck but then added print statements and it works, odd. Here is the working code for reference.

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"C:\Users\neuce\Documents\Projects\HouseMapping\ArcGIS\Figure 01test.aprx")
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(tempSites, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        m = aprx.listMaps()[0]
        print(m.name)
        lyt = aprx.listLayouts()[0]
        print(lyt.name)
        mf = lyt.listElements('MAPFRAME_ELEMENT')[1]
        print(mf.name)
        for lyr in m.listLayers():
            if lyr.name == "Site":
                lyr.definitionQuery = "Match_addr = '{0}'".format(row[0])
                print("DQ applied "+ row[0])
                mf.panToExtent(mf.getLayerExtent(lyr))
                for txt in lyt.listElements('TEXT_ELEMENT'):
                    if txt.name == "Address":
                        txt.text = "{0} \n {1}, {2} {3}".format(row[2],row[4],row[3],row[5])
                print("panned")
                aprx.save()
                print("Saved")
        m = aprx.listMaps()[1]
        lyt = aprx.listLayouts()[0]
        mf = lyt.listElements('MAPFRAME_ELEMENT')[0]
        for lyr in m.listLayers():
            if lyr.name == 'CentralCoastalCounties':
                lyr.definitionQuery = "CNTY_NM = '{0}'".format(row[1])
                print("county DQ applied"+ row[1])
                mf.camera.setExtent(mf.getLayerExtent(lyr))
                #lyr.definitionQuery = ""
                #print("County DQ removed")
                aprx.save()
                lyt.exportToPDF(r"C:\Users\neuce\Documents\Projects\HouseMapping\Figure 1 - {0}.pdf".format(row[0]))
                print("exported")



del aprx
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the same map object that the layout uses.  Then you should be able to perform a defintion query and zoom to the selection without a problem.

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"C:\Users\neuce\Documents\Projects\HouseMapping\ArcGIS\Figure 02.aprx")

lyt = aprx.listLayouts()[0]

mf = lyt.listElements('MAPFRAME_ELEMENT')[0]

m = mf.map
```